# itunesconnect availability date resetting to current date

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect

**itunesconnect availability date selection issue:**

- itunesconnect availability date always resetting to current date. In
  some cases, its not at all showing the availability date.
- We are forced to set the price tier in order to bring the
  availability date. Even after doing so, its not allowing me to set a
  future availability date.
- itunesconnect upgraded its GUI, and these issues are started
  happening after the recent updates. Anyone know what needs to be done
  to set a future date?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue - did you ever get this resolved?

Comment: No Batalia, its not working. It seems that we have to stick with the Version Release Options: 1) Manually release this version, 2) Automatically release this version and 3) Automatically release this version after App Review, no earlier than